# Isn't it wrong to say "good-paying jobs"?

Tags: grammar

I notice that the White House likes to use the phrase "good-paying jobs" (e.g. it's mentioned 5 times in [this recent press release](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2022/08/09/fact-sheet-chips-and-science-act-will-lower-costs-create-jobs-strengthen-supply-chains-and-counter-china/)). But isn't that grammatically incorrect? (the correct phrase being well-paying jobs). Or is there some standard accepted usage, or alternative meaning, for the phrase good-paying jobs?

Comment: Verb-centred compound adjectives are possible, e.g. "strange-looking object", where "strange" is an adjective (_an object that looks strange_). But we cannot match up "good-paying job" with _*a job that pays good_. Instead we'd use the adverb "well", with a past participle as in _a well-paid job_, which matches up with _a job that pays well_.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you are correct in saying that ***well-paying*** is what should be used in this formal context (with *well* as an adverb modifying the participle *paying*). But ***good-paying*** is so popular in informal speech that it seems to gain ground (with *good*, an adjective in origin, used as an adverb - a use which is controversial).

[Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/10/good-paying.html) has a whole article about this.

> Language authorities say “*good*” has been used as an adverb or a quasi-adverb since the Middle Ages, and this adverbial usage wasn’t criticized until the latter half of the 19th century. We believe that in “***good-paying job***,” the word “*good*” is being used idiomatically as an adverb to modify the present participle “*paying*.”

OED, the site says, is more conservative regarding this use of *good* as an adverb. However,

> *Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage* agrees, noting that “good” has been used as an adverb since the 13th century, and that this adverbial use wasn’t criticized until the 19th.

In a 1936 letter, Archibald MacLeish, the poet and Librarian of Congress, says:

> “It pays *good* and keeps the boys in school.”

*Grammarphobia* continues:

> “Our evidence shows that adverbial good is common in the speech of the less educated, but is also known and used by the better educated,” M-W’s editors write.
>
> Ironically, they add, “The schoolmasterly insistence on well for the adverb may have contributed to the thriving condition of adverbial *good*.”

Indeed, [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good) says

> Adverbial ***good*** is primarily *a spoken form*; in writing it occurs in reported and fictional speech and in generally familiar or informal contexts.

I wouldn't be surprised if politicians made use of it in order to reach the masses more. The use of informal terms can give politicians a more down-to-earth image, more accessible to their targeted audience.

In an article about this term on the *[DailyWritingTips](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/good-paying-jobs/)*, Maeve Maddox concludes:

> I think that speakers who prefer “well-paying jobs” to “good-paying jobs” should use it, but unless house style demands one or the other, a writer’s choice should probably stand.

Comment: Even more common is"well-paid", with a past participle as head.

Comment: @BillJ Written without hyphen, the results are [_surprising_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=good+paying+jobs%2Cwell+paying+jobs%2Cwell+paid+jobs&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgood%20paying%20jobs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwell%20paying%20jobs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwell%20paid%20jobs%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Whereas _with the hyphen_, _**well-paying jobs**_ has the _[upper hand](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=good-paying+jobs%2Cwell-paying+jobs%2Cwell-paid+jobs&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgood%20-%20paying%20jobs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwell%20-%20paying%20jobs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwell%20-%20paid%20jobs%3B%2Cc0)_